# Error in xts: 'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, gsub, xts

I download time-series data from [MSCI](https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search): [MSCI-daily](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yn9covoE8mftnCHC1Qug0hzWw7nqbjJK/view?usp=sharing). I found that the dates are not properly formatted, so I need to deal with it.
I use this code to dealing with data-time:

```
daily$Date <- daily$Date %>% as.Date(format = "%b %d, %Y")
for(i in 2:7){
  daily[,i] <- gsub(daily[,i], pattern = ",", replacement = "") %>% as.numeric()
}
daily <- xts(daily[,-1], order.by = daily[,1])
```

But it just appear this line:

```
Error in xts(daily[, -1], order.by = daily[, 1]) : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

Can anyone help me fix this error in r-studio?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```r
daily <- read.csv("~/Downloads/MSCI-daily.csv") 
daily[-1] <- lapply(daily[-1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))) 
daily$Date <- as.Date(daily$Date, format = "%b %d, %Y") 
x <- xts(daily[,-1], daily$Date)
```

You can use `which(is.na(daily$Date))` to find the NA values in the `daily` data.frame.